# XCode 7: AWS S3 Header file not found using Cocoa Pods

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, aws-sdk-ios

I'm trying to get an existing Objective-C project to build in XCode 7 on OS X 10.11 (El Capitan).  I grabbed the source from a repository, ran `pod install`, and then opened up the `.xcworkspace` file and tried to build. It fails to find 'S3.h' which should be getting installed by Pods.

Here is the Pod file:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'

target 'App' do

pod "AWSiOSSDKv2"
pod "AWSCognitoSync"

end

target 'AppTests' do
end
```

Which generates the following `Pods-App.release.xcconfig`:

```
GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = $(inherited) COCOAPODS=1
HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited) "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/AWSAutoScaling" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/AWSCloudWatch" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/AWSCognito" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/AWSCognitoSync" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/AWSCore" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/AWSDynamoDB" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/AWSEC2" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/AWSElasticLoadBalancing" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/AWSKinesis" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/AWSMobileAnalytics" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/AWSS3" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/AWSSES" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/AWSSNS" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/AWSSQS" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/AWSSimpleDB" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/AWSiOSSDKv2"
OTHER_CFLAGS = $(inherited) -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public" -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/AWSAutoScaling" -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/AWSCloudWatch" -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/AWSCognito" -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/AWSCognitoSync" -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/AWSCore" -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/AWSDynamoDB" -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/AWSEC2" -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/AWSElasticLoadBalancing" -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/AWSKinesis" -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/AWSMobileAnalytics" -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/AWSS3" -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/AWSSES" -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/AWSSNS" -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/AWSSQS" -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/AWSSimpleDB" -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/AWSiOSSDKv2"
OTHER_LDFLAGS = $(inherited) -ObjC -l"AWSAutoScaling" -l"AWSCloudWatch" -l"AWSCognito" -l"AWSCore" -l"AWSDynamoDB" -l"AWSEC2" -l"AWSElasticLoadBalancing" -l"AWSKinesis" -l"AWSMobileAnalytics" -l"AWSS3" -l"AWSSES" -l"AWSSNS" -l"AWSSQS" -l"AWSSimpleDB" -l"sqlite3" -l"z" -framework "Foundation" -framework "SystemConfiguration" -framework "UIKit"
PODS_ROOT = ${SRCROOT}/Pods
```

When I then go to build, it fails to find `S3.h` even though it seems to find other files such as `AWSCore.h`.

This project was building successfully on XCode 6.3 about 6 months ago.  Has something changed with the AWS SDK in the last 6 months? Is there some other configuration change that I need to make now that I'm using XCode 7.0.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to add

> pod "AWSS3"

**Edit**

My pod file looks like this

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '7.0'

target 'MyAppName' do

pod 'AWSiOSSDKv2', '~> 2.2'
pod 'AWSLambda', '~> 2.2'
pod 'AWSCognito', '~> 2.2'
pod 'UICKeyChainStore', '~> 2.0'

end

target 'My AppTests' do

end
```

and

```
 #import <AWSS3/AWSS3.h>
```

is working fine for me

Comment: Nope, I closed the workspace, deleted the pods and lockfile, added the AWSS3 pod, ran pod install, re-opened the workspace and tried to build. I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Its #import <AWSS3/AWSS3.h> not s3.h 
working for me

Comment: Looks like this changed in one the SDK updates.  Thanks!